# Phonegap Geolocation connected to Server API

Tags: javascript, php, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Into the mobile app I'm adding GeoLocation for search results which is connected to webserver API however it's always returning "not available".

Javascript

```
function getCurrentLocation()
{   
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess,geolocationError, 
    { enableHighAccuracy: true } ); 
}

function geolocationSuccess(position)
{
    var params="lat="+position.coords.latitude;
    params+="&lng="+position.coords.longitude;
    callAjax("reverseGeoCoding",params);
}

function geolocationError(error)
{
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

PHP (API side)

```
public function actionReverseGeoCoding()
{       
    if (isset($this->data['lat']) && !empty($this->data['lng'])){
        $latlng=$this->data['lat'].",".$this->data['lng'];
        $file="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$latlng&sensor=true";
        if ($res=file_get_contents($file)){
            $res=json_decode($res,true);
            if (AddonMobileApp::isArray($res)){
                $this->code=1; $this->msg="OK";
                $this->details=$res['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
            } else  $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
        } else $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("missing coordinates");
    $this->output();
}
```

And I've defined the permission in config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
```

Any advice please?

EDIT example of @Banik

```
public function actionReverseGeoCoding()
{       
    if (isset($this->data['lat']) && !empty($this->data['lng'])){
        $latlng=$this->data['lat'].",".$this->data['lng'];
        $file="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latlng."&sensor=true";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($res==$data){
            $res=json_decode($res,true);
            if (AddonMobileApp::isArray($res)){
                $this->code=1; $this->msg="OK";
                $this->details=$res['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
            } else  $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
        } else $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("missing coordinates");
    $this->output();
}
```

Comment: are you using the php api only to reververse geocode? nothing else right?

Comment: @banik yes indeed just reversing geocode nothing else, I think my JS code is well return I'm not sure why I'm getting this error

Comment: Actually you have to debug the url what it is getting and paste that url to browser to check the value,otherwise its not possible for us to debug or you can just use jquery ajax function to get the value like 
$.ajax({
      url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+position.coords.latitude+','+position.coords.longitude, 
      success: function(result){
        alert(result[0].formatted_address);
    },
});

and there is another way using google map api to get the address,if you want I can post those methods as answer which is also without php script.

Comment: @Banik thanks for the reply yes please post it as an answer and let be do the troubleshooting at my end. Thanks!

Comment: As you've advised I'm tried the direct browser access and I got {
You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/"} Sounds something wrong

Comment: Okay now try the Ajax call which I posted... and let me know if same is occurring or not...

Comment: I think I found the error it's due to "file_get_contents" which is disabled by server configuration if you look at the PHP side of my question you can find the file_get_contents function I'm trying to replace it with curl function but can't find the suitable structured function.

Comment: okay... I missed it that means in php.ini , allow_url_fopen option was disabled...

Comment: @Banik yes it is however enabling it is risky and I'm trying to replace it with cURL but still not working can you help me with the php side replace with cURL thanks

Comment: try this...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latlng."&sensor=true");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: Please check my question EDIT addition based on your example if the code is well structured :)

Comment: $file="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latlng."&sensor=true"

Comment: Done I'll try and let you know thanks