# cURL not working although installed

Tags: php, curl, fopen, reverse-geocoding

I have a script which was using file_get_contents and due the allow_url_fopen is off for security reason I worked on replacing the code with cURL but it's not working.

Script was BEFORE:

```
public function actionReverseGeoCoding()
{       
    if (isset($this->data['lat']) && !empty($this->data['lng'])){
        $latlng=$this->data['lat'].",".$this->data['lng'];
        $key=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('google_geo_api_key');
        $file="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=$latlng&key=".urlencode($key);
        if ($res=file_get_contents($file)){
            $res=json_decode($res,true);
            if (AddonMobileApp::isArray($res)){
                $this->code=1; $this->msg="OK";
                $this->details=$res['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
            } else  $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
        } else $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("missing coordinates");
    $this->output();
}
```

Now I changed to cURL after:

```
public function actionReverseGeoCoding()
{       
    if (isset($this->data['lat']) && !empty($this->data['lng'])){
        $latlng=$this->data['lat'].",".$this->data['lng'];
        $key=Yii::app()->functions->getOptionAdmin('google_geo_api_key');
        $file="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$latlng."&sensor=true&key=".urlencode($key);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $data= curl_exec ($ch);
        //curl_close ($ch);
        //echo $data;
        if ($res == $data){
            $res=json_decode($res,true);
            if (AddonMobileApp::isArray($res)){
                $this->code=1; $this->msg="OK";
                $this->details=$res['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
            } else  $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
        } else $this->msg=$this->t("not available");
    } else $this->msg=$this->t("missing coordinates");
    $this->output();
}
```

What I did wrong so it's not functioning?

Comment: We need more info. Could you please try to put this `echo 'Curl error num: '. curl_errno($ch);` after `$data= curl_exec ($ch);` and post results to your answer. And why `curl_close ($ch);` is commented?

Comment: And what is this `if ($res == $data){`? You check if `$res`  is equal to `$data`? How could they be equal?

Comment: @gofr1thanks for the reply. 1. $res is an array for jSON callback. I commented curl_close to troubleshoot if the code works or not. I'll update you with the curl_errno within minutes

Comment: I want to pay your attention to this: in BEFORE script `if ($res=file_get_contents($file)){` and in AFTER script `if ($res == $data){`/ In first `=` so left operand gets set to the value of the expression on the right and in second `==`   returns true if `$res` is equal to `$data`

Comment: To more know what I'm talking about please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591717/phonegap-geolocation-connected-to-server-api

Comment: Based on your comment I understand that the code should be $res = $data and not == it should be only One =

Comment: OMG 3 days been hitting my hidden just for = now the issue is resolved but the accuracy of Geolocation isn't 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104755/discussion-between-witon-nope-and-gofr1).